# Impala rounding upto 10 decimal places

Tags: sql, hive, decimal, rounding, impala

I have a column in hive table and I want to use both impala and hive to query that column and it should round upto 10 decimal values.

ie test_column= 32.542999471999998

select test_column should return 32.5429994720. What function I can use in the select query to return the value like this ?

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution.

select cast(test_column as decimal(20,10)) from table_name

This will result into  : 32.5429994720

where as round(test_column,10) is not returning the required result.

Comment: Use the below one. It will be a perfect answer. `select cast(round(test_column,10) as decimal(20,10)) from table_name` Otherwise it will not round off your data but simply takes 10 decimal value.

Comment: Could you specify if you are using Hive or Impala? Your answer seems to be contradicting with the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

on Cloudera 5 / RHEL the result is not like yours (did you use Hive?):

in Impala:

```
Select cast ( 32.542999471999998 as decimal(20,10))
, ROUND( 32.542999471999998, 10)
, cast(round( 32.542999471999998,10) as decimal(20,10))
```

> cast(32.542999471999998 as decimal(20,10)) |
> round(32.542999471999998, 10) | cast(round(32.542999471999998, 10) as
> decimal(20,10))
>
> 32.5429994719    | 32.5429994720  | 32.5429994720